# Swift 2.1, convert string to [String] (not [Character]), how to do that?

Tags: string, swift2

I have a string `var a = "abcd"` and I want to get an array of one-character-string `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`. I've tried `Array(a.characters)` but that only gives me `[Character]` not `[String]`. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "abcd"
let strArr = str.characters.map { String($0) }
```